# d3.JS tooltip doesn't hide on mouse out as expected, and replicates rather than moves on mouse over

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a d3.js scatter plot with both circles and a regression line. For both I want the user to able to mouse over them and see their values. Unfortunately my tooltip is not behaving as expected.

When I mouse onto a circle or the regression path, I don't see one tooltip, I see two tooltips. One is in the top left hand corner of my page, and the second is where I hover over the element.

When I mouse out of an element, the two tooltips that were just created don't "dissappear" (change style to hidden) as expected. Would anyone be able to let me know what I am doing wrong here? I have included my code for the tooltip, mouse outs, mouse overs, handleMouseOut, and handleMouseOver.

```
    const tip =d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class","card")
        .style("padding", "8px")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("left", 0)
        .style("top", 0)
        .style("visibility", "hidden");

        svg.selectAll('circle')
            .on("mouseover", (e, d) => {
                let content = `<div class='tooltip-label'>
                 ${filter_one.org}-${filter_one.type}: ${d[filter_one.org][filter_one.type]} <br/>
                 ${filter_two.org}-${filter_two.type}: ${d[filter_two.org][filter_two.type]}
                </div>`;
                tip.html(content).style("visibility", "visible")
                handleMouseOver(e, d)
            }).on("mouseout", (e, d) => {
                tip.style("visibility", "hidden");
                handleMouseOut(e, d);
              })
              .on("mousemove", (e, d) => {
                tip.style("transform", `translate(${e.pageX}px,${e.pageY}px)`);
              });
            
              svg.selectAll('path')
              .on("mouseover", (e, d) => {
                  let x_value = Math.round(xScale.invert(e.pageX)-(spacing*2));
                  let y_value = Math.round(linearRegressionLine(x_value));
                  let content = `<div class='tooltip-label'>
                  ${filter_one.org}-${filter_one.type}: ${x_value}
                <br/>
                ${filter_two.org}-${filter_two.type}: ${y_value}
                  </div>`;
                  tip.html(content).style("visibility", "visible")
                  console.log(d)
                  handleMouseOver(e, d)
              }).on("mouseout", (e, d) => {
                  tip.style("visibility", "hidden");
                  handleMouseOut(e, d);
                })
                .on("mousemove", (e, d) => {
                  tip.style("transform", `translate(${e.pageX}px,${e.pageY}px)`);
                });
              
    
        const handleMouseOver = (e, d) =>{
            d3.select(e.currentTarget)
              .transition()
              .duration(200)
              .attr("fill", "#334040");
        }
      
         const handleMouseOut = (e, d) => {
        d3.select(e.currentTarget)
          .transition()
          .duration(300)
          .attr("fill", "#5FA19E");
      };
```

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing two tooltips since you only seem to be creating one in this snippet, but you may want to offset your tooltip position so it is not directly under your mouse pointer causing the `mouseout` event to fire continously. So change to `translate(${e.pageX+10}px,${e.pageY-10}px)` for example

Comment: also change `attr("fill"..` to `style("fill"..` in `handleMouseout` and `handleMouseOver` methods